# Are alpha and beta rays also generating electromagnetic rays?

Tags: particle-physics

To discover radio waves in 1886, Hertz used electric sparks between two iron balls. These sparks caused radio waves which generated a current between other balls.
The oscillating charges caused a electromagnetic wave.

But alpha and beta rays also has charged particles, so do they also generate electromagnetic rays? If so, how do they do that?

Comment: Not in a vacuum they don't, unless in the presence of other fields. However, when they hit something, [bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) will take place.

Comment: wouldn't the sparks of Hertz also not generating a radiowave in a vacuum?

Comment: A spark is very different from a free flying charged particle. The key is that fields and velocities change with time.

Comment: Implied in LLIAMnYP's answer is an agent to accelerate charges. Accelerating charges radiate (EM waves).

Comment: So there isn't any acceleration of a alfa or beta particle ray?

Comment: Well, a force field might accelerate them.

Comment: Try to consider, what exactly could cause an acceleration. If there is nothing, but a stream of these particles in a vacuum, the only thing there would be is their mutual repulsion. This is usually negligible, compared to the effect of them hitting something, though something could register. If there's only one particle, then there is nothing to cause an acceleration.